# Huge datafram!! Need help from Jupyter and Python experts

Tags: python, excel, jupyter

I have got a huge data frame that needs to be plotted...

the data set includes 500 rows and each row also contains about 100 datapoints.

Now the problem is this!

for example, lets say that I have a data looks like below,

x_values: 1
y_values: 3-100
(yes for one x values there is 100 different values to be plotted...)

and since I am trying to plot this using Jupyter, I need to set multiple of variables and store all those data points

ex) x_1 = df[4,0] ** this calls the data points in row 3, column 1**

```
y_1 = df[100,1:100]  **this calls the data points in row 100 and column 1 to 100, yes, this is all the data to be plotted with one x-value**
```

now instead of writing the codes like,

x_1 = df[4,0]
y_1 = df[100:1:100]

x_2 = df[5,0]
y_2 = df[101:1:100]

x_3 = df[6,0]
y_3 = df[102:1:100]

x_4 = df[7,0]
y_4 = df[103:1:100]
.
.
.

I was hoping if some one could let me know how to use for loop to make this code into few lines of code!! I would really appreciate if someone let me know which function to look at and learn

Thanks,

Comment: couple of points - we have different definitions of `big` (I will hold back from Crocodile Dundee reference) but 500 by 100 is not big. That aside, I think you will benefit from pivoting your dataframe so the `x-values` are your columns. then look into seaborn to see how to plot the columns.

Comment: About the x_1 … x_4: Basically, you are asking the same as your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72986168/how-to-utilize-for-loop-in-range-with-python … you may want to lookup the concept of arrays (which you are already using in the code)